# Elements of the zero-th Čech cohomology group versus global holomorphic sections

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, sheaf-cohomology, holomorphic-bundles

Something that is confusing (well, to me) has come up in the course of asking other questions.

Let $\pi:V\to X$ be a holomorphic vector bundle of rank $r$ on a complex manifold $X$, such that $V$ is defined by an open cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ and holomorphic transition functions $g_{\alpha\beta}:U_\alpha\cap U_\beta\to\mbox{GL}(r,\mathbb C)$.

If $s:X\to V$ is a global holomorphic section of $V$, then the local data $s_\alpha:U_\alpha\to\mathbb C^r$ of $s$ must glue together as $s_\beta=g_{\alpha\beta}s_\alpha$ over the overlaps $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$.

Global holomorphic sections are also said to be elements of $H^0(X;\mathcal O(V))$, where $H^i$ is Čech cohomology and $\mathcal O(V)$ is the sheaf of holomorphic sections of $V$.

I'm going to assume that the cover $\{U_\alpha\}$ is a "good" cover, for Čech purposes.

Literally, $H^0(X;\mathcal O(V))=\mbox{ker}[C^0(\mathcal O(V))\stackrel{\delta}{\longrightarrow}C^1(\mathcal O(V))]$, where $\delta$ is the Čech coboundary operator, and $C^p(\mathcal O(V))$ is the vector space of $0$-cochains for $\mathcal O(V)$ with respect to $\{U_\alpha\}$.

Hence, a section $s$ of $V$ is in $H^0(X;\mathcal O(V))$ if and only if $(\delta s)_{\alpha\beta}=s_\beta-s_\alpha=0$, which says that $s_\alpha$ and $s_\beta$ must agree *on the nose* over $U_\alpha\cap U_\beta$.

This is different than saying that $s_\beta=g_{\alpha\beta}s_\alpha$ on the overlap.

Having $s_\alpha=s_\beta$ seems to be a very strong restriction on a section.  The existence of such a section suggests that $g_{\alpha\beta}=I_r$ on each overlap, and hence $V$ would be trivial.

But for instance: the holomorphic line bundle $\mathcal O(1)$ (i.e. hyperplane bundle) on $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is non-trivial, and at the same time is supposed to have $H^0(\mathbb{CP}^1;\mathcal O(1))\cong\mathbb{C}^2$.

Something is amiss somewhere in my thinking.  Can someone please help?

Comment: I think your formula for $\delta$ is wrong. It should be the thing that makes everything match up.

Comment: Hmmm...not so sure about that.  See the responses from Hoot and Ted below.

Comment: No, the coboundary is just fine. See my answer below.

Comment: I interpreted $s_{\alpha}$ in the OP's expression for $\delta$ to mean the same thing that it meant earlier. Of course if you change the interpretation then everything is fine.

Comment: It would probably be yseful to readers if you explained exactly what you think is the problem in your example with O(1) at the end. A non trivial bundle may well have two linearly independent sections!

Comment: The paragraph in my question that directly precedes the bit about $\mathcal O(1)$ is the explanation.  (Hoot understood it, and his response is exactly what I was looking for, with regards to every part of my question.)

Comment: You say «But for instance» and then mention the fact that $O(1)$ is not trivial and that it has two linearly independent sections, suggesting then that *that* is an indication of a problem, while it isn't.

Comment: My comments in the paragraph preceding the bit about $\mathcal O(1)$ suggest that $H^0(\mathcal O(1))$ should be just $0$, since it is a nontrivial line bundle and hence has a transition function that is not the identity. But of course it does have sections, as you mention.  Therein lies the problem...which is solved now, by the comments of Hoot, Ted, and Qiaochu.

Comment: The problem is rather in your expectation that nontrivial bundles do not have sections. The rest is just technicalities, really. It is best to adjust your expectations.

Comment: I actually *do* expect nontrivial line bundles to have sections, assuming the degree is positive.  It is just that the way I was calculating $H^0$ was saying otherwise, and I knew there was a problem *because* I was expecting $\mathcal O(1)$ to have sections. Ted's response captures why my $H^0$ calculation was failing. That's all.  :-)

Comment: I meant degree nonnegative.  Also, Mariano, I appreciate your vantage point, but please don't say the "rest is just technicalities".  I am a physicist by training who is trying to become a better mathematician, and a better geometer in particular.  The technicalities are *everything* to me right now, and they are precisely what I am here for.  :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking the Čech point of view requires a lot of vigilance; I think it really gets confusing when you start thinking about divisors and what it means for a section of $\mathcal{O}(D)$ to vanish somewhere. Let's ignore trivializations for the moment.

I hope it's okay to work with sheaves of sections instead of bundles; I think the notation is going to get worse if I try to do it the other way. To that end I'm going to write $U_{\alpha\beta}$ for $U_\alpha \cap U_\beta$. I've got a locally free sheaf $\mathscr{F}$ and to calculate $H^0$ I'm given sections $s_\alpha \in H^0(U_\alpha, \mathscr{F})$ and I need to check whether $s_\alpha|_{U_{\alpha\beta}} - s_\beta|_{U_{\alpha\beta}} = 0$.

If I choose trivializations $\tau_\alpha\colon \mathscr{F}|_{U_\alpha} \to \mathscr{O}_{U_\alpha}^{\oplus r}$ then I can write $s_\alpha = \tau_\alpha^{-1}(v_{\alpha})$ and the condition is 
$$
0 = \tau_\alpha^{-1}(v_\alpha)|_{U_{\alpha\beta}} - \tau_\beta^{-1}(t_\beta)|_{U_{\alpha\beta}} = \tau_\alpha^{-1}(v_\alpha|_{U_{\alpha\beta}}) - \tau_\beta^{-1}(v_\beta|_{U_{\alpha\beta}}).
$$
If your aim is to compare tuples of functions on $X$ then you should probably pick some trivialization over $U_{\alpha\beta}$ and stick with it. If I choose $\tau_\alpha$ for this and hit the equation with it then the requirement is the one you had before:
$$
v_\alpha|_{U_{\alpha\beta}} - (\tau_\alpha|_{U_{\alpha\beta}} \circ \tau_\beta|_{U_{\alpha\beta}}^{-1})(v_\beta|_{U_{\alpha\beta}}) = v_\alpha|_{U_{\alpha\beta}} - g_{\beta\alpha}(v_\beta|_{U_{\alpha\beta}}).
$$
Anyway, there's nothing particularly insightful in the above but I think the way to get past the doubts is to just write it all out and then carry on using transition functions as carelessly as life will allow. For the calculation of $H^0(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^1}(1))$ what ends up happening is that you get functions $f(z)$ and $g(1/z)$ on an overlap and it may seem that the only way to for these to agree is for them to both be the same constant; but we need to multiply $g(1/z)$ by the transition function $z$ in order to be able to compare it with $f(z)$! One might have had this trouble way back when learning the definition of a manifold.

Comment: Nice --- thanks.  I appreciate the vigilance required now, and I also appreciate the vigilance of your response!

Comment: Just to be absolutely sure: when you write $s_\alpha=\tau_\alpha^{-1}(v_\alpha)$, do you mean $t_\alpha$ instead of $v_\alpha$, just to square things up with subsequent notation?

Comment: Yes, I slipped up. One sec.

Answer (score 3):

No, you're confusing notations. For the transition function view, $s_\alpha\colon U_\alpha\to \Bbb C^r$ is a representation of the section in the trivialization. On the other hand, when you come to the Čech viewpoint, $s_\alpha$ refers to an actual section of $V$ on $U_\alpha$.

Comment: So, in other words, there is no issue with how the boundary operator $\delta$ is defined in my question?  Rather, the problem is that the notion of $s_\alpha$ is inconsistent across the two "halves" of the question?  So the representations are related by the transition functions, while the bona fide sections of $V$ on the $U_\alpha$ must agree on the nose on overlaps?  I think Hoot's answer agrees with what you are saying, in any case.

Comment: Your coboundary is fine. I just wanted to give it to you as succinctly as possible!

Comment: That's great, I appreciate it.  Thanks for the help!  :-)